# Function inside factory method can communicate

Tags: angularjs

i have one doubt regarding the factory directory of angular js.

suppose this is fact1 directory .I want to call funct1 method inside the funct2 method.

```
app.factory("fact1",function(){
  return{
     funct1:function(){
        //some code here
     },funct2:function(){
      //some code here
      // call here funct1()
     }
   }
 });
```

first tell me this is possible or not?
if possible then how i can call funct1 method inside the funct2 method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
app.factory("fact1",function(){

    function funct1 () {
        // Do some code...
    }

    function funct2 () {
        // Do some code...
        funct1();
    }

    return{
        funct1: funct1,
        funct2: funct2
    };
});
```

I've personally found this way to be much more usable/readable than stashing every function in my return object. Also, I'm not a big fan of using `this` in my return objects.

Comment: More readable and avoids all the headaches of the `this` keyword.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean they inject 'b' on the 'this'?

Answer (score 11):

Sure it's possible. This is just normal javascript object usage:

```
return {
    funct1: function () {
        //some code here
    },
    funct2: function () {
        //some code here
        this.funct1();
    }
}
```

---

**UPD**. There was a little confusion in comments that it does not work. It does, however you need to understand that it's very important **how** `funct2` method is called. Namely, method should not be detached from it's base object, otherwise `this` context will be different and `this.funct1()` will point to the wrong (usually inexistent) method. Common way to loose context:

```
$('.something').on('click', obj.funct2);
```

In the above, `obj.funct2` `this` will be the HTML element object, not the `obj` anymore. However, below version will work properly:

```
// use anonymous function
$('.something').on('click', function() { obj.funct2() });

// bind explicitly to context
$('.something').on('click', obj.funct2.bind(obj));
```

Here is very important to understand MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: yeah doesn't work - not sure why its the correct answer. did it work for you @Mayur

Comment: @David The code is correct. However you may be using it wrong. Give me a snippet of how you invoke `func2` in your case and I will tell you why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly returning in factory, you can do something like this:

```
app.factory("fact1",function(){
  var obj = {};

     obj.funct1 = function(){
        //some code here
     }

     obj.funct2 = function(){
      //some code here
      // call here funct1()
      obj.funct1();/* calling the funct1 */
     }
     return obj;

 });
```

This should work for you.